# Kitchen utensil identification - tong of some sort

Tags: utensils

My wife got this from a thrift store for a good price; and hey, it would be good for something. The bottom plate has several long slender slots.

[image: Weird tongs]
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like fish tongs. Basically, it's a flat, broad spatula on one side, and a smaller facing surface that can hold a fillet intact while turning it over.

Comment: I wondered if it was a fish tong, but that little round loop, threw me for a loop.

Comment: Yeah, it's an unusual configuration. There are no real standards to a fish time shape based on what I saw trying to image search, so I'm going to assume somebody tried to innovate with the design :)